# How to update a list from an imported script?

Tags: python, list

**`list.py`**

```
value1 = "a"
value2 = "b"
value3 = "c"

list_of_values = [value1, value2, value3]
```

**`main.py`**

```
import list

list.value1 = "d"
print(list.list_of_values)
```

this returns `["a","b","c"]` when I want it to return `["d","b","c"]`. How do I update `list_of_values` in `list.py` so that when it is accessed in `main.py` it returns the proper values for `value1`, `value2`, and `value3`?

Comment: I think you need to do list.list_of_values[0] = "d"

Comment: This will never work the way you want, and it has nothing to do with it being from an imported module

Comment: Also, don't name your module `list.py`

Comment: "how do I update list_of_values in list.py so that when it is accessed in main.py it returns the proper values for value1, value2 and value3" Wait. You showed us an attempt to update *`value1`* expecting it to give a different value for *`list_of_values`*. But you're asking about doing it the other way around. What actually is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

import list

list.list_of_values [0]= "d"

print(list.list_of_values)

Here we are updating the element of the list direct. Additionally I would suggest you to not use list as the file name as it may lead to confusion as it is already a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0):

So you generally don't want to name your files after reserved keywords like list. The other comments below your post mentioning the immutability of references are also important to note.

As I mentioned in my comment, I believe what you want is:

**list1.py**

```
value1 = "a"
value2 = "b"
value3 = "c"

list_of_values = [value1, value2, value3]
```

**main1.py**

```
import list1

list1.list_of_values[0] = "d"

print(list1.list_of_values)
```

**Output:**

```
['d', 'b', 'c']
```

Assuming that you do not need to achieve the output by changing value1